# fcitx5 Japanese input with anty and mozc.. and Dvorak?

Tags: input-languages, japanese

I have been a Dvorak typist for as long as I can remember. I also use Japanese input namely mozc or anthy, but these use QWERTY.

What I would like to know is: is it possible to make the Japanese input accept dvorak rather than QWERTY?